# Firefox, Edge, Safari canvas drawing with putImageData fails

Tags: javascript, canvas

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nragrkb8/3/

I'm trying to get a spectrogram drawn, works in chrome but draws nothing in all other browsers. I'm using getImageData and putImageData to move existing contents down by a pixel every time new data is pushed in. That new data is then drawn into an offscreen image and then putimagedata to apply it to the full canvas.

```
Spectrogram = (function() {

  //constructor function
  var Spectrogram = function(options) {
    //compose options
    this.canvas = options.canvas;
    this.width = options.size; //the size of the FFT
    this.height = options.length; //the number of FFT to keep

    if (typeof options.min !== 'undefined' && typeof options.max !== 'undefined') {
      this.rangeType = 'static';
      this.min = options.min;
      this.max = options.max;
    } else {
      this.rangeType = 'auto';
      this.min = Infinity;
      this.max = -Infinity;
    }

    //set the function used to determine a value's color
    this.colorScaleFn = options.colorScaleFn || defaultColorScaling;

    //precalculate the range used in color scaling
    this.range = this.max - this.min;

    //the 2d drawing context
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d', { alpha: false });

    //single pixel image used to draw new data points
    this.im = this.ctx.createImageData(this.width, 1);

    this.canvas.width = this.width;
    this.canvas.height = this.height;

    //adds a new row of data to the edge of the spectrogram, shifting existing
    //contents by 1px
    this.addData = function (newData) {
      if (newData.length != this.width) {
        console.error('Unmatched dataset size. Expected ' + this.width + ', was + ' + newData.length);
        return;
      }

      if (this.rangeType == 'auto') {
        var changed = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < newData.length; ++i) {
          if (newData[i] < this.min) {
            this.min = newData[i];
            changed = true;
          } else if (newData[i] > this.max) {
            this.max = newData[i];
            changed = true;
          }
        }

        if (changed) {
          this.range = this.max - this.min;
        }
      }

      //move the current contents by 1px
      var im = this.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.width, this.height - 1);
      this.ctx.putImageData(im, 0, 1);

      //draw the new data values into the temporary image
      var j = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < newData.length; ++i) {
        var c = this.colorScaleFn(newData[i]);
        this.im.data[j] = c[0];
        this.im.data[j + 1] = c[1];
        this.im.data[j + 2] = c[2];
        j += 4;
      }

      //put the new data colors into the full canvas
      this.ctx.putImageData(this.im, 0, 0);
    }
  }

  function defaultColorScaling(value) {
    var x = (value - this.min) / this.range;
    if (x < 0) {
      x = 0;
    } else if (x > 1) {
      x = 1;
    }

    var g = Math.pow(x, 2);
    var b = 0.75 - 1.5 * Math.abs(x - 0.45);
    var r = 0;

    return [Math.round(r * 255), Math.round(g * 255), Math.round(b * 255)];
  }

  return Spectrogram;
})();

const size = 1024;
      const length = 200;

      const dataMax = 100;
      const velMax = 1;

      const canvas = document.getElementById('spec');
      canvas.width = size;
      canvas.height = length;

      const spec = new Spectrogram({
        canvas: canvas,
        size: size,
        length: length
      });

      const data = [];
      const vel = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        data.push(0);
        vel.push(0);
      }

      setInterval(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
          data[i] += vel[i];

          if (i > 0) data[i] += vel[i - 1];
          if (i < size - 1) data[i] += vel[i + 1];

          if (data[i] >= dataMax) {
            data[i] = dataMax;
            vel[i] = 0;
          } else if (data[i] <= -dataMax) {
            data[i] = -dataMax;
            vel[i] = 0;
          }

          if (vel[i] == 0) {
            vel[i] = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 100;
          }
        }

        spec.addData(data);
      }, 100);
```

Comment: I'm getting no errors in consoles in edge or firefox.

Comment: You need to set the alpha channel to more than 0 if you want to draw something. https://jsfiddle.net/nragrkb8/10/ Also, note that you should avoid at all costs an high frequency `setInterval` where you perform a task that can take more than the interval (and in your case it can), but rather use something like an requestAnimtionFrame loop. Don't use getImageData + putImageData to update your context, simply use `ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, x, y)`. There might be other things to fix in your code, but here is an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nragrkb8/12/) with these two major things.

Comment: So it seems all the other browsers are ignoring the alpha: false option?

Comment: Also, you should post that as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: `alpha: false` should not concern createImageData, this is a bug in chrome. And I saw this question more as a *typo*, so VTCed instead of answered it. But if you disagree, I may write one.

Comment: if I tell the context that it shouldn't have an alpha channel (as described by mdn) how is that not supposed to apply to everything drawn using the context?

Comment: And in regards to the settimeout, that is just for this example. Plotting random data doesn't seem useful ^_^ Data is actually streamed over a websocket and updated in sync with the data source.

Comment: It will apply to what you draw, but createImageData is not a drawing method, and it must return a new ImageData object, filled with only zeroes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was induced by a misconception:

`getContext('2d', {alpha: false})` should have no incidence on `createImageData` function, so you still have to set the alpha value of your ImageData to something else than 0.

There are also other things in your code that don't go well, even if unrealted with your current issue:

- You should avoid at all costs an high frequency `setInterval` where you perform a task that can take more than the interval (and in your case it can), but rather use something like a [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) loop.
- Don't use `getImageData` + `putImageData` to draw your context on itself, simply use `ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, x, y)`.

There might be other things to fix in your code, but here is an update with these three major things:

```js
Spectrogram = (function() {

  //constructor function
  var Spectrogram = function(options) {
    //compose options
    this.canvas = options.canvas;
    this.width = options.size; //the size of the FFT
    this.height = options.length; //the number of FFT to keep

    if (typeof options.min !== 'undefined' && typeof options.max !== 'undefined') {
      this.rangeType = 'static';
      this.min = options.min;
      this.max = options.max;
    } else {
      this.rangeType = 'auto';
      this.min = Infinity;
      this.max = -Infinity;
    }

    //set the function used to determine a value's color
    this.colorScaleFn = options.colorScaleFn || defaultColorScaling;

    //precalculate the range used in color scaling
    this.range = this.max - this.min;

    //the 2d drawing context
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d', {
      alpha: false
    });

    //single pixel image used to draw new data points
    this.im = this.ctx.createImageData(this.width, 1);

    this.canvas.width = this.width;
    this.canvas.height = this.height;

    //adds a new row of data to the edge of the spectrogram, shifting existing
    //contents by 1px
    this.addData = function(newData) {
      if (newData.length != this.width) {
        console.error('Unmatched dataset size. Expected ' + this.width + ', was + ' + newData.length);
        return;
      }

      if (this.rangeType == 'auto') {
        var changed = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < newData.length; ++i) {
          if (newData[i] < this.min) {
            this.min = newData[i];
            changed = true;
          } else if (newData[i] > this.max) {
            this.max = newData[i];
            changed = true;
          }
        }

        if (changed) {
          this.range = this.max - this.min;
        }
      }

      //move the current contents by 1px
      this.ctx.drawImage(this.ctx.canvas, 0, 1)

      //draw the new data values into the temporary image
      var j = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < newData.length; ++i) {
        var c = this.colorScaleFn(newData[i]);
        this.im.data[j] = c[0];
        this.im.data[j + 1] = c[1];
        this.im.data[j + 2] = c[2];
        // don't forget the alpha channel, createImageData is always full of zeroes
        this.im.data[j + 3] = 255;
        j += 4;
      }

      this.ctx.putImageData(this.im, 0, 0);
    }
  }

  function defaultColorScaling(value) {
    var x = (value - this.min) / this.range;
    if (x < 0) {
      x = 0;
    } else if (x > 1) {
      x = 1;
    }

    var g = Math.pow(x, 2);
    var b = 0.75 - 1.5 * Math.abs(x - 0.45);
    var r = 0;

    return [Math.round(r * 255), Math.round(g * 255), Math.round(b * 255)];
  }

  return Spectrogram;
})();

const size = 1024;
const length = 200;

const dataMax = 100;
const velMax = 1;

const canvas = document.getElementById('spec');
canvas.width = size;
canvas.height = length;

const spec = new Spectrogram({
  canvas: canvas,
  size: size,
  length: length
});

const data = [];
const vel = [];
for (var i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  data.push(0);
  vel.push(0);
}
// our animation loop
function draw() {
  for (var i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    data[i] += vel[i];

    if (i > 0) data[i] += vel[i - 1];
    if (i < size - 1) data[i] += vel[i + 1];

    if (data[i] >= dataMax) {
      data[i] = dataMax;
      vel[i] = 0;
    } else if (data[i] <= -dataMax) {
      data[i] = -dataMax;
      vel[i] = 0;
    }

    if (vel[i] == 0) {
      vel[i] = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 100;
    }
  }

  spec.addData(data);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw();
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
  <canvas style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="spec"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Accepting this as the answer. The problem was my misunderstanding of the alpha:false parameter when acquiring the context; I still needed to set an alpha value for the row of data I was updating. Thanks!

Comment: @TheBurrito What version of chrome are experiencing it? because after testing, nor chrome 64 or 66 on osX seem to be impacted by such a bug.

Comment: Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit) Windows 10